# ROR - using an array within an collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my friends controller I have the following

```
def create
        @friends_array = Array.new

        @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
        @friend = @bill.friends.build(friend_params)
        if @friend.save
            @friends_array << @friend
            redirect_to bill_path(@bill)
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
```

which essentially saves a `@friends_array` that contains a list of names that I can use in my views.

I have three models in my application, a `Bill.rb`, a `Transaction.rb`, and a `Friend.rb`. I am using MongoDB (Mongoid) in this application.

```
class Bill
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :event_name, type: String
  field :urlID, type: String

  # creates a urlID that the users can refer to afterwards
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ urlID }

  # contains many transactions and friends
  embeds_many :transactions
  embeds_many :friends

  #validates the uniqueness of urlID
  validates_uniqueness_of :urlID
end

class Transaction
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :bill

  field :payer, type: String
  field :dollar, type: Integer
  field :cent, type: Integer
end

class Friend
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :bill

  field :name, type: String
end
```

In my view, I simply want to set the `:payer` field in the Transaction Model to one of the names within the `@friends_array`, so I have this on the show page of each bill.

```
<h2>New Transaction</h2>
<%= form_for [@bill, Transaction.new] do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :payer %> <%=f.collection_select(:id, @friends_array, :id, :name)%></p>
  <p><%= f.label :dollar %> <%= f.text_field :dollar %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :cent %> <%= f.text_field :cent %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

I can't seem to get `collection_select` working. The current one returns a `undefined method`map' for nil:NilClass` Error.

If I try `<%=f.collection_select(:friend_id, @friends_array, :id, :name)%></p>` it returns a `undefined method`friend_id'` Error.

If I try `<%=f.collection_select(:bill_id, @friends_array, :id, :name)%>` it returns a `undefined method`bill_id'` Error.

What is the correct syntax for what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined method error comes from the from expecting a method `friend_id` on the object used to create it – in this case, `Transaction.new`. The method you're using will generate a field whose initially selected value is the current value of `friend_id` for the `Transaction` instance, but apparently your model doesn't have this column. You either need to add the column `friend_id` to the `Transaction` model:

```
rails generate migration AddFriendIdToTransactions friend:references
rake db:migrate
```

or you need to use a form field tag for this field instead of a form object method:

```
<%= collection_select_tag(:transaction, :id, @friends_array, :id, :name) %>
```